# Different results for lowest score depending on filter setting

Tags: bug, questions, search, sorting

I was doing something which many stackoverflow users at some point were curious about by searching for a really low scored question.

While doing that, I was taken aback by the fact that the search result seemed strange to me when changing filter setting.

So when I go to questions, then votes, then to the last page, I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874818/pointer-to-generic-pointer-type-safety-is-it-possible) with a score of -28. Now, when I filter for 'java' by clicking on the tag name and doing the same, I find [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990/why-does-i-j-k-j-i-kk-i-j-11) with a score of -33. Shouldn't I have seen the last one in my first search as well?

(Search was done at 2013/04/10 07:25 UTC, I have some favourite tags, but no ignore tags)

Comment: someone once said thats because while you search, new questions are asked and/or added to the list, this way you might end up with different questions.

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler This doesn't apply here, since both questions were already in the system, but the query for all did not show the one limited on java.

Comment: This question was marked as duplicate for some period, but the referenced question was deleted. When people marked it that way, they for sure can provide the answer then here?

Comment: no other questions are added to the list, so you might **not be on the last page**

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler Ok, I see what you mean. But still, if I query for all, go to the last page, I get a page with less than max results and if I manually increase page number in URL, Idon't get a page, so I think the question is not in the result set.